# En mi código utilizando Google App Script puedo reemplazar una celda con un texto normal, pero no una celda con un IMPORTRANGE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Amigos tengo este problema que me esta volviendo loco. En esta spreadsheet tengo dos celdas con el nombre "PETER". Ya realicé el código que encuentra el nombre "PETER" y lo reemplaza. El problema es que solo reemplaza cuando PETER es texto normal , no cuando  PETER es un un IMPORTRANGE.  Como se puede hacer para que también reemplace PETER cuando es una formula importrange ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que realicé :

```
function findAndRemplace(){
    SpreadsheetApp.openById("18M0q55lggPpQ7Ni3p2E0rO-7QwfX3WYjM3Bgm45a_L8")
   .createTextFinder("PETER")
   .matchEntireCell(true)
   .matchCase(false)
   .matchFormulaText(false)
   .ignoreDiacritics(false)
   .replaceAllWith('BRUNO'); 
}
```

Comment: Es porque con importrange() vos estas consultado los valores de un rango de otra planilla SpreadSheet ( seria como una vista ).  Si cambias en el origen vas a ver reflejado el cambio.

Comment: Hola Patrick. Por supuesto, eso que dices. Pero no quiero cambiar el origen. Es más, ese importrange lo voy a reemplazar por otro importrange.